# when using neo4js rest api: deleted properties came back

Tags: neo4j

When I use the `Neo4j REST API`, there seems to be a bug:
A node was indexed by some index. After I deleted some properties of that node, unindex it, and then index it again, those properties came back.

This happens once a while. Not every time.

I'm sure those properties are deleted, by querying that node in the cypher console after the delete operation.

Also, some posts reported this without a satisfying answer: the number of nodes/relationships/properties reported by neo4j webadmin looks crazy. I have 5 (including id 0) nodes, but it shows 932 nodes, 4213 properties. This happens every time. Some people say it's the highest ID in use. I don't think it makes any sense semantically to show the highest ID on the "nodes" label. In addition, the highest ID for my nodes is 466, not 932.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: Hi I'm using version 1.9.

Comment: There was some misunderstanding due to my lack of experience with the "promise" design pattern. Right now I got everything right by closely following the promise-then pattern. No deleted properties coming back. 

Why was my post given a negative vote? The neo4js REST API was poorly documented. That's why I have some trouble understanding the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're judging the properties off the count, instead of off a query?

Neo4j's web console uses meta data to display information like node count, property count, and relationship count. This metadata is not always up to date, but it's much faster to use this then to have to scan the entire Graph Database for this information every time.

Neo4j will adjust these properties every now and then, but it doesn't do a de-fragment of it's information all the time.

Comment: Of course, I'm counting on the result returned by the query. But the number appeared on the gui makes no sense to me. 

But such kind of information seems to be incorrect all the time. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes and No. I'm not sure exactly when Neo4j chooses to compact the numbers, but until they do this, the difference between the 2 are going to be different all the time. If you search, there are resource out there that explain the same thing perhaps in more detail, but the result is the same.

Comment: Just ignore the numbers on that page.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Right now yes I won't pay attention to those numbers.